# VBScript open all files with same extension in a folder

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

I am new to VBScript and I am stuck with the below problem.

I have a folder with some files with the .qvw extension and I want to open all these files and then close them.

I am not able to find any solution which will do this task.

```
sFolder = "C:\test\"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
  If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "QVW" Then
    Set App = CreateObject("QlikTech.QlikView")
    Set newdoc = App.opendoc 
    newdoc.Activate
    newdoc.save
    newdoc.closedoc
  End if
Next​
```

Comment: `If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "QVW" Then` seems the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed line If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "qvw" . i am getting this error  "Microsoft VBSc
ript runtime error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'App.opendoc' "

Comment: `App.opendoc` probably wants a filename argument? How else would it know what file to open? `Set newdoc = App.opendoc(oFile.Name)`

Comment: Thank you @MathieuGuindon - i am getting this error now " runtime error: Object required: 'newdoc' " . Would be you be able to help me out with this please.

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for the API you're using. I don't know the QlikView object model.